# Spring Batch for DB2 to SQL migration in batches of keys

Tags: sql-server, db2, spring-batch

I have a DB2 table with about 150 K records. I have another SQL Server table with the same columns. One of the table columns - let's call it code - is a unique value and is indexed. I am using Spring Batch. Periodically, I get a file with a list of codes. For example, a file with 5 K codes. For each code in the file, I need to read records from the DB2 table, whose code column matches the code in the file and insert a few columns from those records to the SQL Server table. I want to use SQL and not JPA and believe there is a limit (let's say 1000) on how many values can be in the SQL IN clause. Should this be my chunk size?

How should the Spring Batch application to do this be designed? I have considered below strategies but need help deciding which one (or any other) is better.

1) Single step job with reader reading codes from file, processor using a JdbcTemplate to get rows for a chunk of codes and writer writing the rows using JdbcBatchItemWriter - seems like the JdbcTemplate would have an open DB connection through out job execution.

2) JdbcPagingItemReader - Spring Batch documentation cautions that databases like DB2 have pessimistic locking strategies and suggests using driving query instead

3) Driving Query - Is there an example? - How does the processor convert the key to a full object here? How long does the connection stay open?

4) Chaining readers - is this possible? - first reader will read from file, second from DB2 and then processor and writer.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with your option #1.  Your file containing unique `code`s effectively becomes your driving query.

Your `ItemReader` will read the file and emit each `code` to your `ItemProcessor`.

The `ItemProcessor` can either directly use a `JdbcTemplate`, or you can delegate to a separate data access object (DAO) in your project, but either way, with each invocation of the `process` method a new record will be pulled in from your DB2 database table.  You can do whatever other processing is necessary here prior to emitting the appropriate object for your `ItemWriter` which then inserts or updates the necessary record(s) in your SQL Server database table.

Here's an example from a project where I used an `ItemReader<Integer>` as my driving query to collect the IDs of devices on which I needed to process configuration data.  I then passed those ID data on to my `ItemProcessor` which dealt with one configuration file at a time:

```java
public class DeviceConfigDataProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Integer,DeviceConfig> {

    @Autowired
    MyJdbcDao myJdbcDao;

    @Override
    public DeviceConfig process(Integer deviceId) throws Exception {

        DeviceConfig deviceConfig = myJdbcDao.getDeviceConfig( deviceId );
        // process deviceConfig as needed
        return deviceConfig;
    }
}
```

You would swap out `deviceId` for `code`, and `DeviceConfig` for whatever domain object is appropriate to your project.

If you're using Spring Boot, you should have a `ConnectionPool` automatically, and your DAO will pull a single record at a time for processing, so you don't need to worry about persistent connections to the database, pessimistic locks, etc.